# java.util.ServiceLoader not working on WebSphere? no issues on Eclipse

Tags: java, websphere

I have a Java app (with no main) that runs well on eclipse (I have imported Okta Dependencies using Maven https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java), but when uploaded to Tririga ClassLoader, which runs over WebSphere it throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a 'com.okta.sdk.impl.http.RequestExecutorFactory' implementation on the classpath.  Please ensure you have added the okta-sdk-httpclient.jar file to your runtime classpath.
  at com.okta.commons.lang.Classes.lambda$loadFromService$0(Classes.java:205)
  at com.okta.commons.lang.Classes$$Lambda$46.000000002B3AE740.get(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:301)
  at com.okta.commons.lang.Classes.loadFromService(Classes.java:205)
  at com.okta.sdk.impl.client.BaseClient.createRequestExecutor(BaseClient.java:103)
  at com.okta.sdk.impl.client.BaseClient.<init>(BaseClient.java:72)
```

Of course that I included okta-sdk-httpclient.jar to the ClassPath (and other dependencies).

When debugging the app on Eclipse, on com.okta.commons.lang.Classes, the variable 'return' obtains the value Optional[com.okta.sdk.impl.http.httpclient.HttpClientRequestExecutorFactory@5e955596]; but when running on WebSphere, I assume it is assigned with nothing as .orElseThrow is executed:

```
public static <T> T loadFromService(Class<T> clazz, String errorMessage) {
        try {
            ServiceLoader<T> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(clazz);
            Optional<T> result = StreamSupport.stream(serviceLoader.spliterator(), false).findFirst();
            return result.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(errorMessage));
        } catch(ServiceConfigurationError e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(errorMessage, e);
        }
    }
```

WebSphere 9.0.5.0 (Latest as of 08-08-2019)
IBM Java JDK 8.0.5.37 (Latest as of 08-08-2019)
Tririga 3.6.0.4 (Latest as of 08-08-2019)

Not sure where to look, please help.

Comment: If it is a war  file, check the okta related jar files are there in web-inf/lib.

Comment: It is not a war file, I exported the project as a .jar file and had to include the Okta .jars manually on Tririga ClassLoader.

Comment: If it's just a jar file, not a WAR, how is it running "on" WebSphere? Custom service, launchClient, etc.?

Comment: Tririga is the .war file that is running on WebSphere, I uplodad the .jars using Tririga Web Interface.